# Javascript - Stop form submit, self.submit is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to prevent the submit button depending of the result of an ajax call. I tried this:

```
<button type="submit" id="update" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
```

and JS

```
$('#update').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const profiles = $('select#profiles').val();
    const self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getDemosByProfiles',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            profiles: profiles,
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        if(data.status == "success") {
            self.submit();
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            // show some message
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        $.growl.error({ title: 'Error', message: 'Error'});
    });
})
```

But I'mk getting a "Uncaught TypeError: self.submit is not a function".
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `self` if an update button. `submit` is to be used on a form element.

Comment: not possible to prevent it after is happens. Asynchronous 101. By the time the http request returns, the click action is done. So you need to prevent it to start and if it is good, submit the form.

Comment: `self.form.submit();`

Comment: you can use `window.location.reload()` if you want to reload the page after request finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the button, not the form. You need to reference the form.

```
self.form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `button` element has no method named `submit()`.

You want to use `submit()` method on the form element like this:

```
document.querySelector("formSelector").submit()
```

where `formSelector` is the id, class or tag name of the `form` element.